# Im trying to write a naive search code in java for an assesment question but im not entirely sure how to go about doing it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, return

basically the title, the question reads like this:

Write a function called HW2E. This takes an int array of student 
    ID numbers (eg. 14234, and a second int argument, findID. The function 
    should search the array for the specified ID, and returns its location 
    in the array. So, with arguments {11,22,33,44,55,66,112}  and 44,
    it should return 3.   If the search ID is not present in the array,
    then return -1.
    */

```
public int HW2E( int array[]  ,  int studentId  )
{ 
    int correct = -2; 

    return correct ; 
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a homework service.  Are you getting stuck somewhere?  Have you learned about loops?

Answer (score 3):

The below should do it :

```
public int HW2E( int array[]  ,  int studentId  ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == studentId) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You should really go and read a few basic things about java basics and loops though

Answer (score 0):

really the easiest way to do this is converting the array into an list and than use the `indexOf()` function:

```
public int HW2E( int[] array  ,  int studentId  )
{ 
    return Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(studentId);
}
```

But, since it is for school, this would probably be too easy, so I have another solution:
Loop over all items in the list and for every item check if it is equal with `studentID`:

```
public int HW2E( int[] array  ,  int studentId  )
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == studentId) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and, as you may have seen in my solutions, it is not `int array[]`, it is `int[] array`